# Adding default arguments to Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, unix

In order for Google-Chrome to authenticate properly with Kerberized websites using SPNEGO, I need to run chrome with `--auth-server-whitelist=*`.

So far I have been adding that to the last line of `/usr/bin/google-chrome`:

```
exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome"  "$@ --auth-server-whitelist=*"
```

This works fine until there is a new update for google-chrome in which case `/usr/bin/google-chrome` is reset back to it's default.

How can I configure my system to reliably always launch google-chrome with that parameter, even after it was upgraded?

Answer (score 1):

Just make chrome an alias. Add this line to your `~/.bashrc` (you can do similar things for other shells of course):

```
alias chrome='chrome --auth-server-whitelist=*'
```

Then either `source ~/.bashrc` or just open a new terminal and run `chrome`.

---

If you want this to be applied to all users and to work when the program is launched graphically, you should probably write a little wrapper script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --auth-server-whitelist=*
```

Now, check the default `$PATH` for your users. If you save the above script as `google-chrome` in a directory that is in the `$PATH` bur *before* `chrome`'s default location of  `/usr/bin`, then your script will be launched instead of the real `chrome` (remember to set the script to be executable with `chmod 755`). For example, on my system:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

`/usr/local/bin` is before `/usr/bin` so the system will first look there for commands. If I save the script in `/usr/local/bin` it will be launched instead of `/usr/bin/google-chrome`.

You can make sure this will work by tweaking the default `$PATH` set in `/etc/profile`. You run the risk of users setting their own `$PATH` to override this but it is not very likely.

Comment: I understand that will only work in bash and not in gnome.

Comment: @d_inevitable see updated answer. I can't get the aliases to work in the GUI environment, not even if adding them to the various `.profile` and `/etc/profile` or `.bash_login` files which I expected to work. My guess is that the DE uses a special shell invocation that does not read the startup files. Anyway, my suggested workaround should work.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Will try it out when I get back from my vaccation

Comment: It doesn't work for graphical launches as the menu item is referring to `/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Create a shortcut that calls `/usr/bin/google-chrome --auth-server-whitelist=*` and run that shortcut instead

Comment: Thanks but how do I make sure that every user gets to use this shortcut and not the default?

Comment: editing the corresponding file in /usr/share/menu may work

Comment: But then if chrome is run in bash it will not.